# What algorithm should I use when trying to find closest record matches when records contain both categorical and discrete attributes?

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, unsupervised-learning, search

I have 100000 records that have discrete features like topic (analytics etc) and categorical features like ticket details (eg: I need help with analytics for my business). When creating a new record, I would like to see if there is a match with existing records. I thought about using K means for clustering, one hot encoding discrete features and Tf idf on categorical features. Any thoughts?